# Margin Messing Up-- No Margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm new to CSS and Web Design, so sorry if this question is naive.

I'm having a problem with my margins. I would post a JSFiddle, but my problem isn't being replicated on JSFiddle.

### HTML

```
 <div class="messed_up_margin">
        <h1>Messed up Margin</h1>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.messed_up_margin{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    backbround: black;
}

.messed_up_margin h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I am going to assume the margin is from the body... use `body{margin:0;}`.

Comment: That is exactly what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are a bit familiar with CSS. The browser has styles of its own that it automatically applies to elements. Just write all six header tags and open the html file on several different browsers and look at the size and font difference.

The browser also has styles that it adds to `<body>`. Because of this, you must tell the browser how you want it to interpret `<body>`. Techniques to do this are known as CSS Resetting. A Google search will provide you with different ways, [but here is a popular one I have seen:](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for providing an explanation and link also.

Answer (score 1):

Add a type to your declaration. Is it PX? Is it percent? EM? I know you mean zero, but does it know that? (CSS is a jerk...)

Comment: It is absolutely not neccessary to add a unit to 0 in that case.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. It acts the same as before. The answer that Drue posted works. It was because I didn't set the body tag to margin:0px;

Comment: I've actually had that happen to me before. Can't remember what browser it was. It may have been the Dreamweaver testing browser. I know it's not necessary, but it is a good habit to get into.